# How to execute sql file in Gitlab-ci

Tags: oracle, docker, gitlab-ci, sqlplus, dockerhub

I'm discovering gitlab-ci and I want to create a pipeline that executes a sql script after every commit.
For this purpose I used the dockerhub sqlplus image sflyr/sqlplus.

My .gitlab-ci.yml :

```
    stages:
  - build



code_quality:
  stage: build
  image: registry.pic.services.prod/valentine/ci/docker-dind:0.0.3
  services:
    - name: registry.pic.services.prod/valentine/ci/docker-dind:0.0.3
  allow_failure: true
  script:
    - setup_docker
    - docker pull sflyr/sqlplus  
    - docker run -e URL=*/*@//*/* -i sflyr/sqlplus < file.sql

.function: &function |
  function setup_docker() {
    if ! docker info &>/dev/null; then
      if [ -z "$DOCKER_HOST" -a "$KUBERNETES_PORT" ]; then
        export DOCKER_HOST='tcp://localhost:2375'
      fi
    fi
  }


before_script:
  - *function
```

I have the error :

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Mon Dec 30 15:58:59 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred


Enter user-name: SP2-0306: Invalid option.
```

Comment: The problem is that the docker image you are using (`sflyr/sqlplus`) doesn't appear to have `docker` installed. It's probably too light-weight for that. [This](https://gitlab.com/frakman1/codeclimate-test/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml) is an example of a project that uses `docker run` within the `script` block if that helps. It sounds like you need to look for or make a docker image that has both `sqlplus` and `docker` installed.

Comment: thx but I'm confused now because the command :

$ docker run -e URL=<user>/<password>@//xxx.yyy.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1521/ORCL -ti sflyr/sqlplus  is in the overview to connect to oracle db . how can it work if docker isn't installed in the image ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing docker in docker and the answer is simpler than that :

```
    stages:
  - build

code_quality:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - [Runner]
  image: 
    name: sflyr/sqlplus
    entrypoint: ["/bin/sh"]
  allow_failure: true
  script:
    - /instantclient_11_2/sqlplus */*@*/* @file.sql
```